# Windows shutdown timer combined with abort timer

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Because I'm lazy I made these very simple batch files

```
shutdown /s /t 2500
```

and

```
shutdown /a
```

If you are familiar with the Windows command line the first one just sets a timer after which the computer shuts down and the second one aborts this timer.

However they are two separate files. My question is: how to combine them into one? How to make 'if' statement which checks if turn off timer is engaged and aborts it and if it isn't engaged it sets the timer? Just for extra laziness I want to make it one click start/stop timer.

Also if there is a way, can I bind a batch file to specific key combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark the fact that the computer is being shut down by creating a temporary file.
If the file exists, then abort and delete the file.

```
@echo off

set SDF=%TEMP%\shutdown
if exist %SDF% (echo aborting shutdown
shutdown /a
del %SDF%
) else ( echo shutdown initiated
shutdown /s /t 2500
echo XX>%SDF%
)
pause
```

Comment: Thank you.

I ended up with this code only:
    'set SDF=%TEMP%\shutdown
    if exist %SDF% ( shutdown /a
    del %SDF%
    ) else ( shutdown /s /t 2500
    echo XX>%SDF%
    )'
I removed some of it because I dont want the console to pause and therefore I dont need messages on it.